# How to get facebook inbox comments using created date?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter, facebook-comments

I have a requirement to read latest facebook inbox comments using created Date. 
Please let me know the URL for getting latest facebook comments using created date.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get Inbox comments (messages) by using FQL query.

Try calling,

```
FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT thread_id, body, author_id, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id = 1327060333367 and created_time=1277394689'
}, function ( inboxresponse ) {
        //do stuff here with results
});
```

Please note that you need to pass the thread_id and created_time ( in unix timestamp ) and also have "read_mailbox" permission.

Please let me know about this !

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you reply. The url you are provided is upto inbox. but my requirement is getting the latest comments in the inbox using created date. I am using this url : https://graph.facebook.com/me/inbox?fields=comments.  Using this url, i need to get latest comments using created date.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.   I just found out the same FQL query to get the latest comments. but here i am getting the problem with executing FQL query using graph api.  I need to execute with my java program to passing this fql query as url and get the results using OAuth. I am using Scribe API to access the facebook API.

Comment: Please help me how to execute FQL query using java program and Graph api.